# Why this CSS won't be responsive design like this image?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make responsive design.

There are mainly 2 sections such as left and right section.
left section always has to be 300px and right section will be flexible width.

But minimum width has to be 300px and it should be shown on the bottom when it's narrower than 300px(See image below)

Why this CSS won't be responsive design like this image?

This is demo http://jsfiddle.net/5Uy2Y/
In my demo, I didn't put the border for each cell.  Please ignore that.

[image]

**HTML** Can I probably remove `<div class="box">`?

```
<div class="Row">
    <div class="box">
    <div class="Left">  
        <div class="posted_at">July 22, 2013 04:34:14</div>
        <div class="user">John Smith</div>
        <div class="location">California</div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
    <div class="Right">
        <div class="body">Hello, I'm John Smith Nice to know you</div>
    </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.Row{
    border:2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    min-width: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    float:left;
    display:block;  
}

div.Box{
    padding:0px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
}

div.Left{
    width:300px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
    clear:both;
}

div.Right{
    text-align:left;
    clear:both;
    min-width: 300px;
}

div.posted_at{
}
div.user{
}
div.location{
}
div.body{
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use media Query:

```
@media (min-width: 600px) 
{

   .box{
    display:block;
    position:static;
    float:none
   }

}
```

Using Media Query you can write custom css to devices having different widths. Here in this example the `.box` class behaves differently on screen smaller than 600px.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

You can also remove the `.box` class by using jQuery's `.removeClass()` method.

http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

**This is how i would do it without media Queries.**

```
.box{
    padding:0px;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
}

.Left{
    width:300px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
    border:solid 1px black;
}

.Right{
    text-align:left;
    width: 300px;
    border:solid 1px black;
}
```

You can see the Fiddle over here http://jsfiddle.net/5Uy2Y/1/

Comment: Thanks. But I'd like to solve only with regular CSS this time. sorry

Comment: This is regular CSS FYI .This is how a layout is made responsive on different screen sizes.I guess you should do more reading on responsive UI

Comment: Okay Thanks! By the way, why did you put min width 600? why not 300?

Comment: I have upadted my question without media Queries. I used 600 because you said the left box was fixed width of 300 and the right box should have a minimum width of 300 so i just added them both to 600 :P .The size is upto your wish depending on your requirement.